# MySQL Tricky Pivot Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I am having a bit of a problem with a seemingly simple MySQL query. I have spent some days now trying to figure this out. I get close, but I have not been able to replicate the requested output.

Here are the tables:

```
create table Schools(ID int, School1 varchar(10), School2 varchar(10));
insert into Schools Values
  (1, "Robertson", "Addison"),
  (2, "Robertson", "Nester"),
  (3, "Robertson", "Franklin"),
  (4, "Addison", "Nester"),
  (5, "Addison", "Franklin"),
  (6, "Nester", "Franklin") ;

  create table Results(ID int, Score int);
  insert into Results values
  (1, 30),
  (2, 20),
  (4, 60),
  (3, 80),
  (1, 40),
  (2, 55),
  (5, 82),
  (4, 65),
  (6, 38),
  (3, 44),
  (5, 25),
  (6, 53);
```

And here is my required output from the query:

```
School1|School2|Score1|Score2
Robertson|Addison|30|40
Robertson|Nester|20|55
Robertson|Franklin|80|44
Addison|Nester|60|65
Addison|Franklin|82|25
Nester|Franklin|38|53
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also delimiter does not matter, it doesn't have to be pipe.

Comment: homework is designed to make you learn, you need to show what query you have tried. Once you have then, and you need SPECIFIC help THEN ask. Don't just ask the community to do your homework for you. So, what query or queries have you tried? place them in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem:

```
  create table Results(ID int, Score int);
  insert into Scores values
```

Results or Scores??

Easie peasy to do this in PHP do you want the `|` character as a divider. Bit confused.

Comment: That was a typo on my part and not the problem. Thank you so much for pointing that out. I will fix it. It is suppose to be insert into Results values.

Yeah it would be super easy to do this in PHP, however it is an exercise that is required to be done in SQL. :(